# Send money / Request money

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The person you are sending money to is the *recipient* of that money, but what would you call a person you are requesting money from? A *requestee*?

Comment: Can you give some context please. When you say _requesting_, do you mean they are obliged to send you money (for payment of services for example), or that you are merely asking if they will send money (for a donation for example).

Comment: Target, mark, easy touch: these are the words for a scam.

Answer (score 4):

*[Donor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donor)* is a term that is corresponds to recipient, although it has connotations of not receiving goods or services in response.

Another approach is to name them after their role. Who normally pays money? *customers* and *employers*. A more general term is *[provider](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/provider)*, but might equally apply to the recipient, assuming they are selling goods or services.

Another general term is *sender*, which would normally be matched with *receiver*.

Finally, tongue-in-cheek, who do you ask to send you money? Your *mother*.

Comment: Please don’t just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with explicit citations supporting that reasoning.

Comment: Whoops, @tchrist. Didn't realise that was a rule here for single-word-requests. Fixed.

Comment: It was really more of a suggestion that a rule. And thanks, I think it improves your post.

Answer (score 1):

As dangph mentioned in the comments, it really depends on the context of why you're giving them the money.

If the person has no choice but to pay you, for example a [ransom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransom), or court fine, you would be the [**demander**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demander) from freedictionary.com:

> to ask for urgently or insistently: demanding better working conditions; claiming repayment of a debt; exacted obedience from the child; tax payments required by law.

If they were sending the money as a donation or payment, they could be a [**patron**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/patron) (emphasis mine) from reference.com:

> 1. a person who is a customer, client, or **paying guest**, especially a regular one, of a store, hotel, or the like.
> 2. a person who supports with **money**, gifts, efforts, or endorsement an artist, writer, museum, cause, charity, institution, special event, or the like: a patron of the arts; patrons of the annual Democratic dance.

Though you should be careful with this as patron usually implies the money was unsolicited.

Answer (score 0):

If the person is giving you something with the expectation of later compensation or return of the money/item, they are a [lender](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lender), where the lender **loans** the money/item.

In this case the recipient is a [borrower](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/borrower).

If the person is giving you something with no (a cynic might add 'overt' here...) expectation of later compensation or return of the money/item, they are a [donor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/donor), where the donor **donates** the money/item.

In this case the recipient is a [donee](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/donee).